# Is there a word for spear-like?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Is there a word for spear-like?  I don't mean for the components of the spear or the act of spearing, but the noun.

I want something that can be used in the following context: *Her insults were spear-like, rapid, straightforward, penetrating, and designed for maximum damage.*

Comment: Can you provide some context?

Comment: Her insults were spear-like, rapid, straightforward, penetrating, and designed for maximum damage.

Comment: Her insults were like spears, rapid, etc. No need to say spear like. Like spears is better. Unless you say: were spear-like, sharp and pointed.

Comment: Noun?  It sounds like you're looking for an adjective.

Comment: I'd put a colon rather than a comma after “like spears”.

Comment: What about changing the sentence structure a bit. Maybe something like 'Her insults were rapid, penetrating, and designed for maximum damage; like spears she hurled them at her enemies'. Just a thought I also like @Lambie suggestion.

Comment: I'm surprised jab hasn't featured in the answers, given it, along with thrust, are generally the verbs associated with the act of spearing something.

Answer (score 8):

Given your context (spear-like insults), there are a number of words that you can use:

- a sharp insult
- a cutting insult
- a pointed insult

You could also flip things around and use a verb:

> Her insults ______ my pride.

As a verb, you might use:

- cut
- shredded
- stabbed

However, my suggestion would be to use a single word:

> ### [Barb](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/barb)
>
> - a sharp projection extending backward (as from the point of an arrow or fishhook) and preventing easy extraction; also :  a sharp projection with its point similarly oblique to something else
> - a biting or pointedly critical remark or comment

You could also call it a *barbed insult*.

Comment: This answer seems most apt given the context. This is because you are not looking to say your **subject** (insult) is like a **spear**, you are trying to say your **subject** is like **the attack** from a spear.

Comment: I would add *piercing* such as a *piercing remark*.

Comment: @SLC, why don't you add _piercing_ as a formal answer? I think it's a good fit (though I still think _sharp_ is the best fit).

Comment: @alwayslearning I thought it was just another synonym to go with the list, not good enough for it's own answer :)

Answer (score 7):

There are words largely confined to the botanical register for the shape:

> Lance-shaped, **lanceolate** ... : Long, wider in the middle
>
> **hastate**: shaped like a spear point, with flaring pointed lobes at the base

[[New World Encyclopedia](http://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/entry/Leaf)]

Comment: Although these are terrible words used in the provided context.  I would have no idea what either words would have meant.

Comment: @Nelson The context wasn't there when I gave this answer.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Fair enough.  I knew that looking at the edits :)

Comment: 'Although these are terrible words used in the provided context.' should be 'Although these are terrible words when used in the context provided (regrettably, later).'  The question changed almost beyond recognition.

Answer (score 0):

Some other terms that fit the context of insults that bring in some aspects of spears are:

-[Piercing](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/piercing?s=t)
-[Incisive](http://wordsinasentence.com/incisive-in-a-sentence/)

An additional word that fits well in your sentence:
-[Biting](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/biting)